# Clarification about data type overloading (Union Types)

Tags: angular, typescript, types

Actually I saw a line of code on `router.d.ts`, like

```
isActive(url: string | UrlTree, exact: boolean): boolean;
```

Then I quickly learn about it and getting some knowledge about [Union Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4/) in typescript

So I tried it to implement on my application instead of using `Any`

### Statement 1

```
function(param: string | number) {    
}
```

### Statement 2

```
function(param: any) {    
}
```

I understood my **statement 1** is pretty good for limiting data type count from using any (or instead of using any)

---

> But I know typescript is an type safe scripting language. But what about type safe is an possible, if we override datatype's? and share your more knowledge about it.

Comment: whats the question here? something not covered here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: @Digvijay `But I know typescript is an type safe scripting language. But what about type safe is an possible, when we override datatype's? and share your more knowledge about it.`

Comment: I still don't understand the question.
If you use a union type as a function's argument, you should probably use a runtime-compatible test for the argument's type somewhere in the function's body

Comment: @amit . am telling the type safe means `I need every time check the typeof() for which type is coming from the function. So it's not good for the type safe application. just assume If am using 10 datatypes then need check 10 condition to which datatype is currently assigned in the parameter and also we need write more code` does make sense?

Comment: Yes but it still helps for type validation when **calling** the function